# How can i use Vlookup or if to grab adjacent cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

```
0.4  0.7295 0.008082
0.45 0.7332 0.001519
0.45 0.7307 0.03161
0.5  0.7352 0.1174
0.5  0.7345 0.1528
0.5  0.7347 0.127
0.5  0.7323 0.07249
0.55 0.7354 0.1349
0.55 0.7349 0.1475
0.55 0.7321 0.1017
0.4  0.7432 0.1018
0.4  0.7506 0.09984
0.4  0.7529 0.1948
```

What i tried:
    =VLOOKUP(.4,C3:E11,2)
What i want to do is plot all data pertaining to the first column that match the number

Comment: What do you mean by "plot"?  Do you literally want a chart of the data?  Also, note that `VLOOKUP()` will find you one row of data - in this case, probably the first.  It requires a sorted table.  It can also be used on an unsorted table, with a fourth `FALSE` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot for example an average of the second column for each unique value of the first column you could use an averageif statement to create a table of your data for each value of the first column.

Comment: Well, let's say that the first row is just a set parameter, like altitude, and that 2 and 3 are lift and drag or something. Then I want to plot lift versus drag for each corresponding altitude

Answer (score 0):

You could use an excel pivot chart to do this

Put the data into a worksheet with headings, alt, lift and drag then click on 
insert Pivottable > pivot chart

Next move the field list items as follows 
alt to the report filter, 
drag to the Axis fields
lift to the Sigma Values

This should generate a chart for you and you can modify the required options such as chart type, colours etc